# How can I pass an optional function to a view with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a Child view in SwiftUI that can optionally be given a function from a Parent View so that I can perform logic if **action** was NOT given or call **action** in ChildView if it WAS given.

When I try to run my code I am getting **Missing argument for parameter 'action' in call** and I can't figure out why because I marked action as optional in the ChildView so shouldn't it be ok if it's missing when declared in the ParentView?

I marked action as @escaping in the ChildView's public initializer to satisfy the compiler after clicking "Fix" to add @escaping without knowing why or if I should?

If I don't mark action as @escaping I get the error **Assigning non-escaping parameter 'action' to an @escaping closure** in the public initializer.

Maybe the public initializer is causing my issue but I need to include this in my case but think I am initializing the optional function incorrectly?

How can I accomplish what I am trying to do??

**PARENT VIEW**

```
struct ParentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ChildView() // ERROR: Missing argument for parameter 'action' in call???
    }
}
```

**CHILD VIEW**

```
struct ChildView: View {
    
    let action: () -> ()?
    // ^ Should not have to be supplied since marked as optional??

    public init(action: @escaping () -> ()? ) {
        self.action = action
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Tap")
            .onTapGesture {
               if action != nil {
                   action()
               } else {
                  print("No function was given to child view")
               }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just initialize it as `var action: () -> () = {}`, always execute it (won't do anything, as it's empty), but you have an option to override it from the parent, and you don't need an `init` at all.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you haven't declared an optional function but a function that returns an optional Void (whatever that is :)). To make the it optional you need to wrap it in parentheses

```
let action: (() -> ())?
```

And also change the init in the same way and now that the `action` parameter is actually optional `@escaping` is no longer needed. Now we can also give a default value to the parameter

```
public init(action: (() -> ())? = nil ) {
    self.action = action
}
```

So that the view can be called using `ChildView()`

You should also change the usage of the `action`:

```
if let action {
    action()
} ...
```

Comment: Unrelated and perhaps subjective but I prefer `() -> Void` to `() -> ()`

Comment: One can be easily tripped up by the closure syntax, especially when the closure is optional, like in the OP's case. In this situation I prefer a typealias: 
`typealias OnTapAction = () -> Void`. Then the method initializer signature becomes much easier to read: `public init(action: OnTapAction? = nil )`